# Provide PDF form on my Website and save with fillings

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I want to provide a PDF with a form on my Website. It is integrated with an iFrame. When the user has filled it out, it should be save with the user fillings (not empty) on a directory of my Webspace. Is there an elegant solution to this possibly using PHP? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Because you can't control what browser is used, you can't control what PDF viewer is used to fill the form. Some embedded PDF viewers won't even be capable of filling form fields. My recommendation is to collect the data using standard HTML, then populating the form using any one of the several PHP libraries that can populate PDF forms, then present that to the user and have them sort of "approve" it, at that point, you save it to your Webspace.

That said, there are solutions like Adobe Sign that will convert the PDF to and HTML5 rendition that allows you to fill the form in any browser then retrieve the data and/or a static PDF for storage on your Webspace.